# Need Help determining groups on python

Tags: python

I need help fixing (Or rewriting) an algorithm. It works out how many hours you have worked in a day and gives you points based on how long you work. This is what i have so far

```
Amount = ""
Currency = 0
print("Enter Your Figures in 24 hour clock")
print("")
import os;
from time import sleep

sleep (2)
print("You Currently Have "+Amount+" In Your Account!")
from time import sleep

print("When did you leave work?")
Left = input(": ")
print("When did you arrive at work?")
Arrival = input(": ")

Total_Hours = (int(Left) - int(Arrival))
print("900 = 9:00")
print("You worked "+Total_Hours+"")

if TH 1 < TH <=401:
    print("You Have Received 4 Points!")
    print("Try to work harder!")
    Amount = Currency + 4
    print ("Your New Balance is " + str(Amount))
```

I was wondering how I would put the TH into a group such as if hours worked is between 1-4 hours then output something. and if worked between 5-8 hours output something else etc. Becuase i get a syntax error at `if TH **1** < TH <=401:`I have found various ways on the internet before coming here but none seem to have worked. Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Replace `if TH 1 < TH <= 401:` with `if 1 < TH <= 401:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Amount = ""
Currency = 0
print("Enter Your Figures in 24 hour clock")
print("")

print("You Currently Have " + Amount + " In Your Account!")

print("When did you leave work?")
Left = input(": ")
print("When did you arrive at work?")
Arrival = input(": ")

Total_Hours = (int(Left) - int(Arrival))
print("900 = 9:00")
print("You worked %s." % Total_Hours)

if 1 < Total_Hours <= 401:
    print("You Have Received 4 Points!")
    print("Try to work harder!")
    Amount = Currency + 4
    print("Your New Balance is " + str(Amount))
```

TH did not exist but Total_Hours does...
By the way you should read PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank You that seems to have worked !

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if-else statement instead:

```
if total_hours < 4:

    print('You worked less than 4 hours, try to be more productive')

elif total_hours <= 8:

    print('You did just enough')

else:

    print('Way to go, more than 8 hours today')
```

Comment: I tried this but when it gets to a point it does all the IF statements and gives all repsonses